# Youtube auto-embed not working in post

Tags: youtube, embed

The youtube embed feature should work even if you don't use any special tag - just posting the URL of the video in a free line of your post.

the autoembed is working from the index.php page, visible through the teaser section. But inside the post itself, the embed doesn't work. I already set evertything in the Media section, and i'm using the HTML tab on the post edit. Any ideas? Wordpress 3.3.