# YouTube embed not working on Node + React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, youtube, embed, http-status-code-401

In a [node+react app (LINK)](https://guarded-forest-66906.herokuapp.com/en/video) I have a page where I must show different videos which parameters are taken from a .json copy

**Data JSON:**

```
        {
            "content": {
                "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/tE3_NyCs90I?rel=0&showinfo=0"
            }
        }
```

**React export:**

```
export default props => (
  <section className="video">
    <iframe className="videoIFrame" src={props.content.url} frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
  </section>
)
```

The page source **is composed correctly**, but the video embed does not load properly, all I can see is a still image and the play button but nothing happens when I hover or click it.

```
<section class="video">
    <iframe class="videoIFrame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tE3_NyCs90I?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>
```

In the **console** I see these errors:

```
> Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube: insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. The default protections will be applied.

> POST https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_interaction? alt=json&key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8 401 ()
```

**What I tried so far:**

- Installing `react-youtube` and replacing the plain html rendering with the premade component. Same errors.
- Tried changing the videos so it's not the same video repeating. Didn't solve.
- Checked the following questions without luck
- [Youtube embed not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076049/youtube-embed-not-working) - Not relevant.
- [Youtube Embed code is not working in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568080/youtube-embed-code-is-not-working-in-html) - Not relevant.
- [Youtube embed not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375678/youtube-embed-not-working-in-chrome) - Didn't work.
- [Youtube auto-embed not working in post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000998/youtube-auto-embed-not-working-in-post) - Not relevant.
- [YouTube embedded player throwing 401 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504749/youtube-embedded-player-throwing-401-errors) - Not relevant, I don't presume I necessarily need to embed a video from my own channel.
- [Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection - Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714879/error-parsing-header-x-xss-protection-google-chrome) - Not relevant, this would mean all sites that embed YouTube videos would have the same problem on my PC. Also I tried Safari, Firefox and IE and have the same issue, although IE shows no console errors for some reason.

I'm out of options, does anyone have some advice?

Thanks in advance for your replies. Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm, it was only a rogue CSS `z-index` that masked the entire video section.

Sorry for bothering you guys.